# Win8.1 freezes on boot with hypervisorlaunchtype=Off unless I briefly disconnect SSD

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, ssd, hyper-v, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 (model 12943QG) from 2012, running Windows 8.1 x64. I've upgraded the laptop with a Samsung 840 PRO SSD of 512GB to use as the system drive instead of the tiny 128GB stock Intel SSD. The Samsung SSD has an up to date firmware version, the Windows installation is fully patched, and I'm running recent driver versions in so far as I can find them for this relatively old machine.

I have the machine set-up to have 2 boot loaders for Windows 8.1, one with Hyper-V enabled and the other with Hyper-V disabled. I use the latter for when I need to use VirtualBox, which needs Hyper-V disabled in order to run its own hypervisor.
I initially created the Hyper-V-disabled boot loader using `bcdedit \copy ...`, as explained [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx). But I always have trouble booting into it. It tends to work once after creating the boot loader but after rebooting the machine it hangs at the blue Windows logo, leaving me only with the Hyper-V-enabled boot loader. I've tried recreating the boot loader(s) many times (also using `bcdedit /create` instead of `/copy`) and eventually I even rebuilt the entire bcd store from scratch. All to no avail: the Hyper-V-disable boot loader hangs on every 2nd boot attempt.

However, after much trial and error I found a simple, yet utterly baffling, method to boot into the Hyper-V-disable mode every time. Believe it or not but the trick is:

- fully power down the laptop;
- pull out the SSD & slide it back in right away;
- power on the laptop.

Afterwards Windows 8.1 boots into the Hyper-V-disabled mode without problems. But annoyingly I need to do this every time I want to get into this mode after a restart (even without having used the Hyper-V-enabled mode in the meantime). Clearly this is a waste of time and because I often work on the go it also means I need to carry around a screwdriver to be able to open up the drive hatch whenever I want to reboot.

I have roughly 2 questions:

- What could be causing this weird situation?
- Could there be an alternative way achieve the same result without having to physically disconnect the SSD?

In case it matters this is my current bcd configuration:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-UK
inherit                 {globalsettings}
integrityservices       Enable
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {cecf0999-8220-11e5-82e0-806e6f6e6963}
displayorder            {default}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8.1 (Hyper-V enabled)
locale                  en-UK
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {1c96e7d5-8220-11e5-82dd-806e6f6e6963}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 8.1 (Hyper-V disabled)
locale                  en-UK
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {cecf0999-8220-11e5-82e0-806e6f6e6963}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with Lenovo ThinkPad T420 Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit. I need Virtual Box with Laravel Homestead, but the VM would not run and error message is about the VT-x/AMD-V not being enabled. After a quick search found out that Hyper-V has to be removed or disabled. First I tried to remove it altogether by deselecting the entire Hyper-V group in the "Turn Windows features on or off" page. After reboot, the system booted as normal until the blue Windows logo disappears, at that state it froze. Tried several times, took off the battery and the power cord, that did not help. Had to perform the system recovery using a restore point which ran successfully. Then on the recovered system with Hyper-V active I tried the second approach with a copy of the bootloader entry (bcdedit copy and hypervisorlaunchtype off). The result now is the same, the system boots until the blue logo disappears and then freezes. Luckily, this time I am able to boot normally thanks to the default choice left in the bootloader. Note: I did not try the trick with disconnecting the HDD.

P.S. This was intended as a comment, but I was not able to add it because of restrictions. :(

Edit: Was able to boot with the Hyper-V disabled and to use VirtualBox after changing BIOS Virtualization settings to the following:

- Intel (R) Virtualization Technology: enabled
- Intel (R) VT-d Feature: disabled

Turns out, VT-d Feature causes the issue with hanging during the boot. Maybe this helps in your case, too.

Comment: You're relating a "me, too" experience, but it isn't clear how somebody would use the information to help solve their problem.  If you believe there is helpful information here, can you edit your answer to better focus and explain it; turn it into something actionable?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Mr.Key! It seems that disabling VT-d also solved the problem for me. I've been able to boot with Hyper-V disabled without first having to disconnect my HDD. Hurray!

Comment: This does not really explain what you did to solve the problem, I assume you wanted `hypervisorlaunchtype` to be set to `auto` instead of `off` but its not clear what you did unless your saying disabling `VT-d` fixed it for you. This comment stims from the fact, I went to research `hypervisorlaunchtype` and came across this incomplete answer.